# Deleting rows of matrix based on duplicated values of a column in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia, delete-row

Here is another challenge in Julia. Imagine when have the following matrix:

```
 5.0  3.54924
 6.0  3.54702
 6.0  3.54655
 7.0  3.54168
 7.0  3.0
```

I want to delete the rows of the matrix for which the elements of the first column are duplicated. That will produce the following matrix, for example:

```
 5.0  3.54924
 6.0  3.54702
 7.0  3.0
```

Deletion of rows are arbitrary since we don't keep repeated values for the first column. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can simply do it using DataFrames.jl (the performance will be worse as you perform the conversion twice, but the code is simpler):

```
julia> A = [5.0  3.54924
                   6.0  3.54702
                   6.0  3.54655
                   7.0  3.54168
                   7.0  3.0]
5×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 5.0  3.54924
 6.0  3.54702
 6.0  3.54655
 7.0  3.54168
 7.0  3.0

julia> Matrix(unique(DataFrame(A), 1))
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 5.0  3.54924
 6.0  3.54702
 7.0  3.54168
```

Alternatively you could write

```
julia> A[.!nonunique(DataFrame(A[:,1:1])),:]
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 5.0  3.54924
 6.0  3.54702
 7.0  3.54168
```

which is a bit faster and uses less memory but more messy.

Comment: Thank you! I also thought about data frames, but as I was worried about speed and memory, I was looking for a less time-consuming solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a function that does this, but here is one example:

```
function unique_rows(A::AbstractMatrix{T}) where T
    # find the index of unique rows
    row_indices = Int[]
    row_values = Set{T}()
    for i in 1:size(A, 1)
        v = A[i, 1]
        if !(v in row_values)
            push!(row_indices, i)
            push!(row_values, v)
        end
    end
    # construct the new matrix
    B = similar(A, (length(row_indices), size(A, 2)))
    for j in 1:size(A, 2), i in 1:length(row_indices)
        B[i, j] = A[row_indices[i], j]
    end
    return B
end
```

Applied to your example:

```
julia> A = [5.0  3.54924
            6.0  3.54702
            6.0  3.54655
            7.0  3.54168
            7.0  3.0]
5×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 5.0  3.54924
 6.0  3.54702
 6.0  3.54655
 7.0  3.54168
 7.0  3.0    

julia> unique_rows(A)
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 5.0  3.54924
 6.0  3.54702
 7.0  3.54168
```

Comment: Ok! Will try your solution, as my goal is to avoid a time-consuming solution. Thank you!